# SAT Reading Question Practice Test #6

Tags: exam-questions, reading, reading-comprehension

> Harouni of course became familiar with this
>   ubiquitous man, who not only accompanied him on
>   his tours of inspection, but morning and night could
>   be found standing on the master bed rewiring the
>   light fixture or in the bathroom poking at the water
>   heater. Finally, one evening at teatime, gauging the
>   psychological moment, Nawab asked if he might say
>   a word. The landowner, who was cheerfully filing his
>   nails in front of a crackling rosewood fire, told him
>   to go ahead.
>
> “Sir, as you know, your lands stretch from here to
>   the Indus, and on these lands are fully seventeen tube
>   wells, and to tend these seventeen tube wells there is
>   but one man, me, your servant. In your service I have
>   earned these gray hairs”—here he bowed his head to
>   show the gray—“and now I cannot fulfill my duties
>   as I should. Enough, sir, enough. I beg you, forgive
>   me my weakness. Better a darkened house and proud
>   hunger within than disgrace in the light of day.
>   Release me, I ask you, I beg you.”
>
> The old man, well accustomed to these sorts of
>   speeches, though not usually this florid, filed away at
>   his nails and waited for the breeze to stop.
>   “What’s the matter, Nawabdin?”

This excerpt from the SAT practice test is questioned. It asks for the purpose of the second paragraph. The choices are as follows:

```
A) flatter Harouni by mentioning how vast his lands are.
B) boast to Harouni about how competent and
reliable Nawab is.
C) emphasize Nawab’s diligence and loyalty to
Harouni.
D) notify Harouni that Nawab intends to quit his
job tending the tube wells.
```

The answer is C. But, why is it not D. Can anyone please explain? Thank you for your help

Comment: What part of the paragraph do you think indicates D? I don't see it.

Comment: @user3169 Well, for starters, he says "Release me" and "I cannot fulfill my duties”. Isn't the whole second paragraph leaning towards D?

Comment: Fulfilling ones duties is not necessarily related to employment status. "release me" is asking the employer to let him leave, which would be the employer's action. "Nawab intends to quit his job" would involve the employee's action (quitting would be his decision).